# Ruby Tracepoint - Attach hooks to open3 child processes

Tags: ruby

I am playing around with the great Tracepoint API, and I was wondering if it is possible to attach event hooks to ruby processes that I am launching using popen3?

An example:

```
TracePoint.trace(:end) do |e|
  # Here we do something like logging this event.
end


Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  # cmd is a ruby cmd, and we want the tracepoint above to apply to it as well
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: drb server is one option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution for popen3, but a simple `exec` did the trick.